# MySQL Sub Queries With WHERE condition outside

Tags: mysql

Is this possible in sub queries?

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE age is not null) as NAME,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE age is null) as NamewithoutAge FROM table WHERE name in('List of name')
```

instead of

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE age is not null and name in('List of name')) as NAME,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE age is null and name in('List of name')) as NamewithoutAge
```

Comment: both look like an unnecessary use of a sub query. What do you want a query to return?

Comment: Please show us the actual table names and some sample data.  Yes, in general you may have scalar subqueries which appear in a higher level select this, but then again you may not even need to use this approach.

Comment: Both queries will not even run unless the subqueries return only 1 row.

Comment: i change count(*) instead of names

Comment: @Rain how does the answer that you accepted solve your problem? The code has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

You can use the results of a query in the select part of the query

```
SELECT (SELECT name FROM t2 WHERE t2.age is not null and t1.id = t2.t1_id ) as NAME
        FROM t1 WHERE name in('List of name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(age is not null) as NameWithAge,  
  SUM(age is null) as NamewithoutAge
FROM table
WHERE name in('List of name')
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(field)` counts `NOT NULL` values only. So

```sql
SELECT 
  COUNT(age) AS name_count,
  (COUNT(*) - COUNT(age)) AS name_without_age_count 
FROM employee
WHERE name in('List of name')
```